# Limited number of results in Google Search using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to do a custom google search from python. I found the relevant code at [developer.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#fonje).

My Code:

```
url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web'
       '?v=1.0&q=teen%20wolf%20s02e01%20divxstage.eu&userip=USERS-IP-ADDRESS')

request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': "http://www.my-ajax-site.com"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

results = simplejson.load(response)
print results
```

As you can see I am querying for `Teen Wolf S02E01 divxstage.eu`. The above script returned a [json response](http://pastie.org/4027579).

Now, when I simply search for `Teen Wolf S02E01 divxstage.eu` from my browser the first link that google gives me is the link of site `divxstage.eu` which is my required link.

Now, if you closely look at the `json response` it doesn't contain the `divxstage.eu` link and the results are also limited.

So, my question is why there is a **difference in output** of the above two approaches and how do I customize my query to get the required `divxstage.eu` link which is `www.divxstage.eu/video/6qihgxf1ejzx1`.

Comment: Initially I assumed this was search personalization in effect, but I tried it on my own Google account and anonymously and in both cases I also got divxstage.eu results first.

Comment: @AndrewG.: Yes I forgot to add that I also tried anonymously and got `divxstage.eu` as first result but when I try it `programmatically` the divxstage url is not all present in the json response.

Comment: The results are limited (at least in quantity) because you're not specifying a results size (`rsz`) parameter with your query.  If you don't specify it it defaults to "small" which is currently 4 (which is the number of results you're getting).  See [this reference](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/reference#_intro_fonje) (scroll to "Standard URL Arguments").  nb it appears that there the maximum size you can specify is 8.

Comment: Also, [it looks like this is a known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=43) with no details about if/when the two results sets will will ever match.

Comment: @jedwards: I tried that still no luck. The number of results surely increased but it doesn't contain any link for `divxstage.eu`.

Comment: Right, I don't know if there is an answer to the other half of your question, basically "why are results missing?" -- this last link I posted has a pretty long discussion about your issue, but no resolution unfortunately.

Comment: @jedwards: I can limit my results using `site:divxstage.eu` but I don't have any idea how to do that. I mean how do I pass `site:divxstage.eu` as parameter in my above code.

Comment: @jedwards: Your If you can suggest any alternative way to query google search engine and retrieve the url.